# array error moving row to new sheet if column contains

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been working on a script to move a row based on answers in Column B to a different sheet. I think I am most of the way there as it does move the rows but I have a few kinks to work out and could use some advice.

Here is the condensed version of code I am running:  (I removed some of the urls 
 and other "valueToWatch" variables and other "ts" sheets etc, just so you didn't have to sort through long code. ):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1sYuI'),
sheetOrg = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var value1ToWatch = "ANDERSON";
var value2ToWatch = "BARNES";
var ts1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Ppms');
 sheet1in = ts1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var ts2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1BY8YOQ');
   sheet2in = ts2.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

var arr = [], 
values = sheetOrg.getDataRange().getValues(),
i = values.length;

while (--i) {
 if (value1ToWatch.indexOf(values[i][1]) > -1) {
    arr.unshift(values[i])
   sheetOrg.deleteRow(i + 1) 
  sheet1in.getRange(sheet1in.getLastRow()+1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr); 
};

 if (value2ToWatch.indexOf(values[i][1]) > -1) {
    arr.unshift(values[i])
   sheetOrg.deleteRow(i + 1) 
  sheet2in.getRange(sheet2in.getLastRow()+1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
};
}
}
```

one problem I am having is I get this failure notice even though it is transferring the data.

> TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 41, file "Code")

Comment: On Google Apps Script, the error messages usually include the filename and line number. What is the line that the error message refers to? By the other hand, each question should contain one question otherwise it's too broad for this site model. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks.  What it hard to do a screen shot in replies but what it is telling me is:   Error Message 
11/29/17 12:03 PM  /  myFunction / TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined. (line 41, file "Code") / time-based / 11/29/17 12:03 PM

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the textual error message. By the way usually is best the text error message than a screenshot.

Comment: Which one is the line 41?

Comment: In my code lines 35  - 40 are the first "while (--i)"  and line 41 is blank.  line 42 starts the next "if" statement for looking at value 2.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem by creating a [mcve].

Comment: And thanks, I have update the question to just apply to the error question, and will post a new question about the other question